# How to achieve similar sql:select a, count(distinct(b)) from x group by a with kafka stream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My idea is:

First groupByKey then ip, device is unique, then map [ip, device] ip is the key device is value.
GroupByKey again, I think the count value is the number of devices corresponding to ip.

Kafka record is

key               value(ip,deviceId)

1                127.0.0.1,aa-bb-cc

2                127.0.0.1,aa-bb-cc

3                127.0.0.1,aa-bb-cc

.....（more， but all value are 127.0.0.1,aa-bb-cc）

I want to get the number of deviceIds owned by ip in the hopping time window.

code：

```
final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
final KStream<String, String> records = builder.stream(topic);
KStream<String, String> formatRecoed = records.map(new KeyValueMapper<String, String, KeyValue<String, String>>(){

        @Override
        public KeyValue<String, String> apply(String key, String value) {

              return new KeyValue<>(value, key);
         }
}
formatRecoed.groupByKey().windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(1000 * 60).advanceBy(1000 * 6).until(1000 * 60)).count().toStream(new KeyValueMapper<Windowed<String>, Long, String>(){
        @Override
        public String apply(Windowed<String> key, Long value) {
            return key.toString();
        }

    }).map(new KeyValueMapper<String, Long, KeyValue<String, String>>(){

        @Override
        public KeyValue<String, String> apply(String key, Long value) {
            String[] keys = key.split(",");
            return new KeyValue<>(keys[0], keys[1]);
        }
    }).groupByKey().windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(1000 * 60).advanceBy(1000 * 6).until(1000 * 60)).count().toStream(new KeyValueMapper<Windowed<String>, Long, String>(){
        @Override
        public String apply(Windowed<String> key, Long value) {
            return key.toString();
        }

    }).map(new KeyValueMapper<String, Long, KeyValue<String, String>>(){

        @Override
        public KeyValue<String, String> apply(String key, Long value) {
            return new KeyValue<>(key, "" + value);
        }
    }).to("topic");
```

The expected result Each time window is

key       value

127.0.0.1@1543495068000/1543495188000    1

127.0.0.1@1543495074000/1543495194000    1

127.0.0.1@1543495080000/1543495200000    1

But my running result is：

127.0.0.1@1543495068000/1543495188000    3

127.0.0.1@1543495074000/1543495194000    4

127.0.0.1@1543495080000/1543495200000    1

Why is that？

I am looking forward to someone helping me.

Answer (score 1):

There are two windows in your code and this may be the cause of the issues. I'd propose this flow:

```
records.map((key, value) -> {
      String[] data = value.split(",");
      return KeyValue.pair(data[0], data[1]);
    })
    .groupByKey() // by IP
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(1000 * 60).advanceBy(1000 * 6).until(1000 * 60))
    .reduce((device1, device2) -> device1 + "|" + device2)
    .toStream() // stream of lists of devices per IP in window
    .mapValues(devices -> new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(devices.split("|"))) // set of devices
    .mapValues(set -> set.size().toString())
```

Resulting KStream is windowed stream of `(IP, count(distinct(devices)))` (both strings), so you can forward it to other topic. The method assumes that there is one character that doesn't exist in devices names (`|`), if there is no any you'd need to change serialization method.